# jQuery replaceWith() not working correctly when using indexOf()

Tags: jquery, html, css

What's wrong with this code? I want to replace one `img` by another one according to the condition...

jQuery (I think that the main problem is inside the if condition, maybe it's not recognizing the `this.src`):

```
$(document).ready() {
    $("#firstdiv img").replaceWith(function () {
        if(this.src.IndexOf("soccer2") > -1) {
            return $("<img src='/images/soccer ball.jpg'/>")
        }
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="firstdiv" class="divvv">
    <img src="/images/Soccer.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="soccer icon" />
    <img src="/images/soccer2.jpg" alt="soccer icon" width="60" height="60" />
</div>
```

Comment: Simply opening up your browser dev tools console would point right at the error thrown. Then type that error in your favorite search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `IndexOf`. It should be : `indexOf`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#firstdiv img").replaceWith(function () {
    if (this.src.indexOf("soccer2") > -1) {            
      return $("<img src='/images/soccer ball.jpg' alt='replace one' />");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstdiv" class="divvv">
  <img src="/images/Soccer.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="soccer icon" />
  <img src="/images/soccer2.jpg" alt="soccer icon" width="60" height="60" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `replaceWith` in the OP code returns only when the condition is met, if not by default `undefined` will be returned and the image element will be removed from DOM.

Also, note that `IndexOf` should be `indexOf`(*lowercase `i`*)

Here's [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c2xan09p/) of non-working code.

Although, the issues can be solved by returning the same element if the condition is falsy.

```
$("#firstdiv img").replaceWith(function () {
    if(this.src.indexOf("soccer2") > -1) {
        return $("<img src='/images/soccer ball.jpg'/>")
    }

    // else, return the same element
    return this.outerHTML;
});
```

---

A better approach would be to use attribute contains selector

```
$('#firstdiv img[src*="soccer2"]').replaceWith('<img src="/images/soccer ball.jpg"/>');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c2xan09p/1/)

Comment: @Tushar this is a good answer, although I was trying to figure out what's going on this code, I made a mistake writing IndexOf instead of indexOf...

Comment: @AlexGH I've also explained that. :)